# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'excpt.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How to solve this problem.
This problem appear when I run one of my codes which I had written.
I use visual studio 2010 ultimate to write the code

Comment: Exactly what the error says, it cannot find the file. Is it in the same directory as where you are trying to include it? Otherwise use a relative path `#include "..\..\folder\folder\excpt.h"` or a full path `#include "C:\folder\folder\excpt.h"` for example.

Comment: Well, find the file and fix the path.

Comment: Please provide a mini auto contained sample of the code that produce that error, info about the compiler settings and all the info you can provide (platform, win version, etc...), all this info increase probability of getting a response.

Comment: It is a common installation problem, just google the error message.

Answer (score 1):

in the options dialog you can tell vs where to look for include files. Look for

```
Projects and solutions>VC++ Directories
```

Answer (score 0):

file location : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src
if you don't find, may be re-install VS2012